# Owasp Zap module in python not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.8, zap

I have created a script to perform an spider scan using owasp zap module from python. However, when start the script I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _`enter code here`make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: http://zap/JSON/spider/action/scan/?apikey=&url=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.23 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/vuln_discovery/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    spider_scan(url)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/vuln_discovery/zap.py", line 12, in spider_scan
    zap.spider.scan(url=url)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zapv2/spider.py", line 215, in scan
    return six.next(six.itervalues(self.zap._request(self.zap.base + 'spider/action/scan/', params)))
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zapv2/__init__.py", line 192, in _request
    data = self._request_api(url, get)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zapv2/__init__.py", line 172, in _request_api
    response = self.session.get(url, params=query, proxies=self.__proxies, verify=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    enter code here

requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: http://zap/JSON/spider/action/scan/?apikey=&url=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.23 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))`
```

Comment: Hello, could you please provide some of your code, in order to reproduce the error?

Comment: zap = ZAPv2(proxies={'http':'http://localhost:8090','https':'https://localhost:8090'})
    zap.urlopen(url)

    zap.spider.scan(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)

    while (int(zap.spider.status(zap)) < 100):
        # Loop until the spider has finished
        print('Spider progress %: {}'.format(zap.spider.status(zap)))
        time.sleep(2)
    print('Spider completed')

Comment: How are you starting ZAP and what clients have you allowed?

Comment: Im using kali linux virtual machine which has owasp Zap installed. I am opening it as root.

Comment: You don't seem to have disabled or provided the API key.

Comment: I am trying to run a scan for my local website (127.0.0.1) which I built some time ago and it doesn't have an API key. What should I do if I don't have an API key?

Comment: I meant the ZAP API key.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that helps but I just had a similar problem with similar errors. For me the Port was not set properly. Maybe you can check the port with
`sudo netstat -tunlp` if the port there is really